# php artisan config:clear warning date_default_timezone_get()

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to execute `php artisan config:clear` I've been doing this without problems for last 6 months, and now after a composer update I'm getting this error:

`[root@XXX]# php artisan config:clear`

PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to useezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting thiu most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to seleone. in /var/www/html/cne-pnp/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 311

In Loader.php line 228:

Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.

I don't know what to do now, it's making a warning from vendor files... and I can't clear my cache now. Any hint?

EDIT: By the way, I've just tried a `composer update --no-scripts` without success.

Comment: You need to update the timezone within the php.ini

Comment: I don't get it, why should be that? I haven't touch anything strange. What I have to do there? I'm looking php.ini and don't know what I have to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all

```
composer clearcache && composer update
```

then go your `php.ini`

and change this value

```
date.timezone= Yourtime zone
```

for more information about timezones 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

in your `.env`

```
APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_LOCALE_PHP=en_US
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
```

**P.S**

Never ever do the composer update in production, updating packages in production can cause a conflict. also, make sure to take a backup of your 
`composer.lock` file

Comment: Y tried that too, and I get this a similar error: `>Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize In Loader.php line 228: Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes. Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1`

Comment: @pmirnd In your .env `APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_LOCALE_PHP=en_US
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC`

Comment: LOL, I found  another mistake... in .env I had `MAIL_FROM_NAME=SOME - NAME` with out double quotes... now I can clear my cache, let's see the composer update. But the original question was to clean the cache, so it's fixed now.

Comment: @pmirnd I am glad it helped you